Spivak Exercise 3-39: Proving Change of Variables using Sard's Theorem
$\DeclareMathOperator{\ext}{ext}$
In Exercise 3-39 of Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, Spivak asks the reader to use Sard's Theorem to prove the following (which is his original change of variables theorem, without the assumption $\det u'(x)\neq 0$):

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and let $u:A\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be an injective, continuously differentiable function. If $f:u(A)\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable, then
$$\ext\int_{u(A)}f=\ext\int_A(f\circ u)\lvert \det u'\rvert$$

Here I have used the notation $\ext\int_A$ to specifically denote Spivak's extended integral on $A$, which is defined over open sets in terms of partitions of unity. (Specifically, it is defined as $\sum_{\varphi\in\Phi}\int_{\mathop{\mathrm{supp} }\varphi}\varphi f$ assuming $\sum_{\varphi\in\Phi}\int_{\mathop{\mathrm{supp}}\varphi}\varphi |f|$ converges for a partition of unity $\Phi$ subordinate to an admissible open cover of $A$). Spivak does not spend much time on the properties of the extended integral, which has led me to some confusion when citing facts about the integral.
Here is my attempt so far. I have bolded three claims that I am not entirely sure how to justify.

Let $C=\{x\in A:\det u'(x)=0\}$. Since $u$ is continuously differentiable, $\det u'$ is continuous. This implies that $C$ is closed in $A$, so $A\setminus C$ is open in $A$ and thus in $\mathbb{R}^n$. ($*$)
Thus the restriction of $u$ to $A\setminus C$ is injective and continuously differentiable with $\det u'\neq 0$, so it satisfies the conditions of the original change of variables theorem, and we have
$$\ext\int_{u(A\setminus C)}f=\ext\int_{A\setminus C}(f\circ u)\lvert \det u'\rvert$$
Since $u$ is injective, $u(A\setminus C)=u(A)\setminus u(C)$. By Sard's Theorem, $u(C)$ is of measure zero. So
$$\ext \int_{u(A)}f=\ext\int_{u(A)\setminus u(C)}f=\ext\int_{u(A\setminus C)}f\tag{$**$}$$
Since $(f\circ u)\lvert \det u'\rvert=0$ on $C$, we have
$$=\ext\int_{A\setminus C}(f\circ u)\lvert\det u'\rvert=\ext\int_A(f\circ u)\lvert\det u'\rvert\tag{$***$}$$
and the conclusion follows.

$(*)$ is a minor point to check that I am operating correctly in the subspace topology.
$(**)$: I am not sure how to prove the first equality here. I would like to write
$$\ext\int_{u(A)}f=\ext\int_{u(A)\setminus u(C)}f+\underbrace{\ext\int_{u(C)}f}_{=0}=\ext\int_{u(A)\setminus u(C)}f$$
However, it is not clear to me that $\ext\int_{u(C)}$ is even defined, since $u(C)$ may not be open. Is there another way to prove equality?
$(***)$: Similarly, I am not sure how to prove equality here, since we can't necessarily split the extended integral over $A\setminus C$ and $C$.
I would appreciate any additional information about how to prove these equalities. If the proof needs to take a different direction, I would not mind pointers, but I am not looking for a complete proof that is completely different from this one.
